# jQuery multiple pseudo :not selector with descendant combinator

Tags: jquery, css

I have some markup like

```
<div class="a"><img></div>
```

and

```
<div class="b"><img></div>
```

I need to dynamically wrap img with a div and use `$(":not('.a, .b) > img")` to select them.

Unfortunately I also have some markup like

```
<div class="c"><div><div><img></div></div></div>
```

so the > child combinator won't work. I guessed `$(":not('.a, .b, .c) img")` will work for all but that is not the case.

What do I miss? How can I select all img tags that are several class but at different child levels?

Thanks for help

Comment: Sometimes chaining `.not()` methods are easier. Can get ugly, but if you use jQuery, it's expected eventually.

Comment: `:not(.foo) .bar` usually never works, because almost all elements will have _some_ ancestor somewhere up the line that does not match `.foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I miss?

`:not('.a, .b, .c)` matches the inner `div`s that don't have any classes, which are also ancestors of the `img`.

You might be able to use some combination of `:not` and jQuery's [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) extension, but I think I'd probably do it manually, something like this:

```
// Using jQuery
$("img").each((_, el) => {
    const $el = $(el);
    if (!$el.closest(".a, .b, .c").length) {
        // ...wrap the element...
    }
});
```

or

```
// Using the DOM directly
for (const img of document.querySelectorAll("img")) {
    if (!img.closest(".a, .b, .c")) {
        // ...wrap `img`...
    }
}
```

since the DOM has [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) now.